# Why are the Powershell class instance missing inherited parameters?

Tags: c#, powershell

So I am working my way through the first steps at trying to build a Powershell Provider using powershell instead of c#. So I have converted a C# example to the following code (still a work in progress):

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Provider
using namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel

[CmdletProvider(
   "K8s",
   [System.Management.Automation.Provider.ProviderCapabilities]::None
)]
class K8sProvider : NavigationCmdletProvider {

    [boolean] IsValidPath([string] $path){ return $true; }

    [Collection[PSDriveInfo]] InitializeDefaultDrives() {
        [PSDriveInfo] $drive = [PSDriveInfo]::new(
            "K8sDrive", $this.ProviderInfo, "", "", $null
        );
        return @($drive);
    }

    [bool] ItemExists([string] $path){ return $true; }

    [bool] IsItemContainer([string] $path) { return $true; }

    [void] GetChildItems([string] $path, [bool] $recurse) {
        $this.WriteItemObject("Hello", "Hello", $true);
    }
}

$t = [K8sProvider]::new()
$t.InitializeDefaultDrives()

return $t
```

And when I save that out and source it to a test variable
`$t = . .test\testProvider.ps1` It errors trying to create the $drive variable saying that $this.ProviderInfo is null, this appears to be a parameter that is supposed to be inherited from the NavigationCmdletProvider class or am I missing something?

My intent is to eventually include this in a PowerShell module that I can import the module and use the provider to interact with apps such as kubernetes and docker, so it should appear when running `get-psprovider`.